# Fiddler stops capturing when I close DestroyTwitter

Tags: http, fiddler

I'm trying to capture HTTP(S) traffic between my machine and an external REST service using Fiddler, as it seems Firebug isn't giving me detailed enough info.  DestroyTwitter polls frequently and pollutes my capture history, but when I close Destroytwitter, Fiddler doesn't capture anything at all, while still showing the icon that it is capturing.  Why is this?

Comment: have you tried closing DestroyTwitter first and then starting Fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up Firefox to actually *use* Fiddler's proxy? In Advanced » Network » Connection » Settings, Firefox has [several options](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Advanced+panel#Network_tab) for proxy settings:

1. No proxy: Fiddler will not work.
2. Auto-detect proxy settings for this network: Fiddler *might* work? (I don't know.)
3. Use system proxy settings: Fiddler will work, if you have chosen to have it change the system wide settings.
4. Manual proxy configuration: you will have to enter the Fiddler details yourself.

As DestroyTwitter did get captured, I assume Fiddler has changed the system wide proxy settings. Hence, I guess the third option in Firefox should work.

Comment: It was indeed the proxy, with your second option working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Closing any application shouldn't impact Fiddler's ability to capture in any way.  You can easily use Fiddler's process filters to ignore the "Destroy Twitter" program.